# Get a list of string as input from user in loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, this is a basic question

How do you get a list of string as input from the user? I tried:

```
array = []
for i in range(0,4):
    array[i] = input("Enter string")
```

This has an error. I know I am wrong. How do we get a list of strings as input?

Comment: `.append` them.

Comment: `array = [input("enter string") for _ in range(4)]` will do

Comment: Append them forms a line, I want a list. That can be accessible like array[i]. Does appending help this

Comment: Append works. I though it would be like in c# where it appends to a string already. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has size 0, this is why you can't access any elements (or assign to them). The correct code would be:

```
array = []
for i in range(4):
    array.append(input("Enter string"))
```

Comment: Works. Thanks @Sekuraz

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(4):
    array.append(input("Enter string >>"))
```

Since your array doesn't have any values yet, assigning to `array[i]` would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Concise:

```
array = [input("Enter string: ") for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Indeed this is elegant but in python 2x input() evaluates the string as a variable and throws a NameError. In python 2x I would recommend using raw_input() rather than input(). But since this question is tagged under  python3x it's preferred :D

Comment: Thanks for noting this in case someone using Python 2 tries to use it. Links to the relevant entries in the Python 2 documentation: [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) & [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Answer (score 0):

when range limit is unknown i.e., when (n) needs to be taken as an input from the user,

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of names in list for input:"))
a = [input() for i in range(n)]
```